# Mac OS option key shortcuts not working, how to make it work?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a very long line which I want to view as wrapped.

There is an option called word wrap that can help me achieve this.

Anyhow the shortcut method `option + z` doesn't work, instead inserts a `ˀ` there.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like one of your extension might be overriding your VSCode config. Try `⌘+SHIFT+P`/`CMD+SHIFT+P` and then search for `View: Toggle Word Wrap`/`Toggle Word Wrap`.

You will then be able to see the shortcut assigned to that command on your local PC. Alternatively, `⌘+SHIFT+P`/`CMD+SHIFT+P` and search for `Keyboard Shortcuts`. In there search for `OPTION+z` and check for the answers which pop up.

[image: Word Wrap via Shortcut Panel]

[image: Wordwrap Key Binding]

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I wanted to know how to make the option key work.

Comment: First see if the option key is even mapped to the command. If it isn’t add the key binding to “Toggle Word Wrap”